# CSS Float with 4 divs

Tags: css

I have 4 divs within the footer div of my site and I can't get the floats to work properly so they sit correctly.

This is the structure;

`<div class="footer">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
</div>`

Div One needs to be full width and run the full length of the page above the other three which should all sit next to each other taking up a third of the page each.

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simply like:

```
#one {
  width: 100%;
}

#two, #three, #four {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}
```

Output can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/1r07t5L4/4/).

You can also extend this with unknown DIV names by utilising `.footer div:nth-of-type(1)` instead:

```
.footer div:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer div {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}
```

I've created an extendable output [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/yf1ozu7r/1/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is float `#two,#three,#four` and assign a width of 33.3%, but you likely also want to clear the overflow from `.footer` via `overflow: auto;` or some other clearfix technique.

```
.footer {
  overflow: auto;
}
#two,#three,#four {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this with flexbox

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#one {
  width: 100%;
}
#two,#three,#four {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```